# Running time RF

Tags: random-forest, high-dimensional

I am running a randomForest on my personal data. Dimension is 600-1500 features (numeric, strings and factors) for 22,000 observations (number of trees =300). Running time is about **15 days**. RF is said to don't suffer from **curse of dimensionality**. Therefore, what could explain this crazy amount of running time?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is your `max_depth` for each decision tree? I'm surprised that you actually waited 15 days for it.

Comment: It is actually an hyperparameter that is out of my control I think (I am using the standard option https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf). The only parameter I have chosen is setting to 300 the number of trees grown

Comment: I saw that max_depth may be equivalent to "nodesize". After selecting a very high number for nodesize (10,000) code is much faster: 1786.815s. Thanks! :) @gunes

Answer (score 0):

Curse of dimensionality has *nothing* to do with how long the code runs. I’m also surprised with how long did it run for you. If you check [those benchmarks](https://github.com/szilard/benchm-ml) the running time for random forest with 100k samples was between 20 and 1200 *seconds*, those are more realistic timings. Either you have insufficient computational resources (speed, RAM), or this is some kind of bug. Restart computer, maybe re-install the package and all the dependencies, check system monitoring & logs for strange things & memory usage etc.

Comment: Thinking it was due to one of the motives you mentioned before I actually run the model in both my personal computer and my school server. I did also try to increase the the memory in R. Both timings in my personal PC and in the server were pretty close (above 14 days)

Comment: As said above, this is several orders of magnitude slower it should run, so I’d expect bug in your code.

Comment: I am very new on these techniques. Can you explain more on bug? I attach here the line I use for my code to run.                                                                                                 rf_model <- randomForest(future_outcome ~ ., trainData, 
                           ntree = 300, 
                           importance = T)

Comment: @vog this is not a reproducible example, you’d need to share all your code and all your data. Nonetheless, it’s not a place for code review. The code should run up to few hours, if it’s not, something is wrong.